# My consumer thread isn't reading my producer thread's products correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

so I'm doing a school project involving creating two pthreads, one that acts as a producer, one that acts as a consumer, communicating via a shared bounded buffer.  I threw in some debugging lines that print a statement on the console each time the producer creates a new int to put in the buffer, and displays another line when the consumer is reading the number.  It looks like they stay in synch for the first two, with the producer making one item, the consumer reading one item, etc., and then the producer makes everything, and the consumer just reads the final product, ignoring the ones in the middle.  Here's my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_cond_t empty;
pthread_cond_t full;
int done = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
int BUFFER_SIZE = 5;
int buffer[5];

void *consumer();
void *producer();

int main() {
pthread_t tidC;
pthread_t tidP;

pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&full, NULL);

pthread_create(&tidP, NULL, &producer, NULL);
pthread_create(&tidC, NULL, &consumer, NULL);

pthread_join(tidC, NULL);
pthread_join(tidP, NULL);

return 0;
}

void * producer() {
int seed = 6;
int reps = 7;
int num = 0;
int i = 0;

srand(seed);
printf("Producer in for\n");/*DEBUG*/   
for(i; i<reps; i++) {
    printf("Producer making item %d\n", i);
    num = rand();

    while(pthread_cond_signal(&full))
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &lock);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);/*entering critical section*/

    buffer[in] = num;

    pthread_cond_signal(&full);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);/*exiting critical section*/

    in++;

    if(in == BUFFER_SIZE) {
        in = 0;
    }
}

done = 1;
}

void * consumer() {
int num = 0;
int min=0;
int max=0;
int avg=0;
int numItems=0;
int first=1;
int reps = 3;
int sum = 0;    

printf("Consumer Entering While\n");/*DEBUG*/

while(!done) {
    while(pthread_cond_signal(&empty)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&full, &lock);    
    }

    printf("Consumer reading item %d\n", numItems);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); /*enter critical section*/

    num = buffer[out];

    pthread_cond_signal(&empty);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); /*exit critical section*/  

    out++;

    if(out == BUFFER_SIZE)
        out = 0;

    /*processing*/

    if(first) {
        min = num;
        max = num;
        sum = num;
        first = 0;
        numItems = 1;
    }
    else {
        if(num < min)
            min = num;

        sum =+ num;

        if(num>max)
            max = num;

        numItems++;
    }
}


avg = sum/numItems;/*calc avg*/

/*report stats*/
printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
printf("Average: %d\n", avg);
printf("Items Produced: %d\n", numItems);
 }
```

My output is then:

```
Producer in for
Consumer Entering While
Producer making item 0
Consumer reading item 0
Producer making item 1
Producer making item 2
Producer making item 3
Producer making item 4
Producer making item 5
Producer making item 6
Consumer reading item 1
Minimum: 2726
Maximum: 25069
Average: 12534
Items Produced: 2
```

Any advice???

Comment: First, fix the compile-time errors: `for (i;`. Second, I'm virtually certain `sum =+ num;` is supposed to be `sum += num;`, and that would be flagged by any reasonable warning-enabled compilation. Third, your thread procedures aren't `return`-ing anything; they need to. And *none* of that touches on the *multiple* problems with unprotected predicate access, a mutex that isn't properly initialized, seeding `rand()` on multiple threads (which at-best is implementation-speific), etc.

Comment: Is it just me or you are not locking the mutex prior to entering the pthread_cond_wait()? You're supposed to lock the mutex prior to waiting; on the other hand, you better unlock prior to signaling.

Comment: @user16653 its worse than that. The OP seems to think the condition variables *are the predicate* rather than a signal mechanism for notification of a change in predicate data variables. Thats a hard hill to get over, and near everyone that first starts using pthreads makes that mistake the first time.

Comment: I followed your advice, @user16653 , and put the waiting after locking the mutex, and the signal after unlocking.  Now my output's showing the producer making a few, the consumer reading a few (asynchronously), and it only reading 5 items (it's supposed to read 6).

Comment: @user198881 I can write something up on this if I get the time. Your general concept of how condition variables, their paired mutex, and predicate data are interrelated is flawed. They don't work the way you seem to think they do. An explanation would be .. involved .. to demonstrate the correct way of doing this, so if I have the spare time I'll try and write something up unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: @WhozCraig , when I add a return void to the functions, I get an error, "expected primary expression before 'void'.  If you get the chance I'd appreciate it; I used the functions provided by the teacher as he told us.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my output's showing the producer making a few, the consumer
>   reading a few (asynchronously), and it only reading 5 items (it's
>   supposed to read 6).

That's due to your use of the variable `done` - the producer sets `done = 1` shortly after it has made item 6, and the consumer tests `!done` before it reads an item, so it may well exit the `while` loop without having read and processed the last items. See below for a possible solution.

> when I add a return void to the functions, I get an error, "expected
>   primary expression before 'void'.

Of course - we cannot return a type; e. g. `return NULL` would be correct.

Here's a version of `producer()` and `consumer()` that incorporates several improvements (note that I renamed the condition variables `empty` and `full` to `nonfull` and `nonempty`, respectively, to accurately describe their meaning):

```
void *producer()
{
    int seed = 6;
    int reps = 7;
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    srand(seed);
    printf("Producer in for\n");/*DEBUG*/   
    for (; i<reps; i++)
    {
        num = rand();
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);/*entering critical section*/
        if (in == out+BUFFER_SIZE)  // buffer full?
            pthread_cond_wait(&nonfull, &lock); // if so, wait
        printf("Producer making item %d\n", i);
        buffer[in++%BUFFER_SIZE] = num;
        pthread_cond_signal(&nonempty);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);/*exiting critical section*/
    }
    done = i;
    return NULL;
}

void *consumer()
{
    int num;
    int min;
    int max;
    int avg;
    int numItems = 0;
    int first = 1;
    int sum = 0;    
    printf("Consumer Entering While\n");/*DEBUG*/
    while (!done || numItems < done)
    {   // loop as long as not all produced items are consumed
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); /*enter critical section*/
        if (out == in)  // buffer empty?
            pthread_cond_wait(&nonempty, &lock);    // if so, wait
        printf("Consumer reading item %d\n", numItems);
        num = buffer[out++%BUFFER_SIZE];
        pthread_cond_signal(&nonfull);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); /*exit critical section*/  
        /*processing*/
        if (first)
        {
            min = num;
            max = num;
            first = 0;
        }
        if (num < min) min = num;
        sum =+ num;
        if (num > max) max = num;
        numItems++;
    }
    avg = sum/numItems;/*calc avg*/
    /*report stats*/
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min);
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
    printf("Average: %d\n", avg);
    printf("Items Produced: %d\n", numItems);
    return NULL;
}
```